# Cassaforte client/prepared with multi.cql

Tags: clojure

Is the client/prepared macro only applicable to the .cql namespace and not .multi.cql?

I use multi.cql to control my cluster and session construction, and executing normal queries is fine. However, if I attempt something along the lines of:

```
(client/prepared
  (insert session :some_table {:id "some-id"
                               :value "some-value"})))
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to com.datastax.driver.core.Session
at clojurewerkz.cassaforte.client$prepare.invoke(client.clj:174) ~[classes/:na]
at clojurewerkz.cassaforte.client$execute.doInvoke(client.clj:278) ~[classes/:na]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at clojurewerkz.cassaforte.multi.cql$execute_.invoke(cql.clj:17) ~[classes/:na]
at clojurewerkz.cassaforte.multi.cql$insert.doInvoke(cql.clj:132) ~[classes/:na]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
```

My session is constructed fine, I can use it to execute normal queries. 
I'm relatively new to Clojure, so it's possible I'm doing something stupid.

If client/prepared is not applicable to .multi.cql - how can I use multi and prepared statements? I see there is an option to force-prepared-queries when creating the cluster, that's a little brute force but probably acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug that has been fixed with the latest release (1.1.0) of Cassaforte:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-cassandra/JFUtS4k70w8